# codeigniter callback doesn't work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is a simple login validation script in codeigniter.
I can't understand the problem. I have gone through the user guide but the callback just doesn't work.

```
public function form_validation()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim        |alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', `enter code here` 'required|trim |xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|xss_clean|callback_validate');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo "validated but not logged";
    } else {
        $this->load->view('errors/formerror');

    }
}

public function validate()
{
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    if ($this->model_users->can_login()) {
        echo "Logged";
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate', "Incorrect username/password");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function form_validation()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim |xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|xss_clean|callback_email_check');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo "validated but not logged";
    } else {
        $this->load->view('errors/formerror');
    }
}

public function email_check($email)
{
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    if ($this->model_users->can_login($email)) {
        echo "Logged";
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', "Incorrect username/password");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add `_check` suffix like `callback_email_check` and callback method `email_check` and check. Find more here [CodeIgniter Callbacks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

Comment: You forgot to add `return true` and `return false` in `email_check` method

Comment: And need remove `echo`  :)

Comment: @Winston, that is as it was in question. I think the questioner will consider. may be he want to see whether the method is running...

Comment: the callback is working...but somehow I can't invoke the model and it's showing.... validated but not logged  i.e. going straight to the form_validation_run part.....

Comment: public function can_login()
{
  $sitekey="My Key";

  $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));

  $this->db->where('password_hash',md5($this->input->post('password')));

  $this->db->where('password_salt',md5($this->input->post('password').$sitekey));  
  $login_query =$this->db->get('users');
  if($login_query->num_rows == 1)
    {return true;}
  else return false;

}

Answer (score 0):

I got myself into a mess like this one and almost drowned for a long day. Here was the problem. I was working with a model and it turns out that the function needed for callback was not working while in a model. To fix this:

**Ensure that the function you are using for callback is in the controller and not in the model.**

It worked like magic. I can't figure why but it fixed my callback case.

Adding *check suffix doesn't make that much difference as the manual said nothing about suffixes in particular. The prefix callback* is what I know should never be left out. I have several callbacks that have worked without the _check suffix.

Here is what the manual says:

> To invoke a callback just put the function name in a rule, with "callback_" as the rule prefix. If you need to receive an extra parameter in your callback function, just add it normally after the function name between square brackets, as in: "callback_foo[bar]", then it will be passed as the second argument of your callback function

What I did notice was the example in the manual had the callback function in the controller and not in the model.